# Validate variable for spaces before and after certain symbols

Tags: php

I will like to correct POST variable for typing errors after submit.

So if user type keywords like this: Value1&&Value2||Value3

Then it should add a space before and after these symbols: && ||

Also if user types two spaces before the symbols then it should be corrected to only one space.

Final result should look like this: Value1 && Value2 || Value3

I have tried this:

```
$newString = str_replace("&&"," && ", $string);
$newString = str_replace("||"," || ", $string);
```

I need to figure out how I can check for spaces if input is entered correct.

I hope someone has a great solution for this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Stackoverflow isn't a place to get free code.

Comment: Sorry for not including things I have tried, this does the job when spaces are missing: str_replace("&&"," && ", $string); but then i need to check for space before and after so i can skip above if it is entered correct.

Comment: Can any of the values contain spaces? If not, just strip out all the spaces first, then your current str_replace will work.

Comment: Yes spaces should be allowed in keywords, so it should only add a space before and after the separator symbol if its missing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Convert into an array of values seperated by && and ||.
2. Trim the values in the array.
3. Convert the array into a string with your spacing.